# Improving player button control code

Tags: javascript

Would somebody be kind enough to show me the best way to loop through this so it much more efficient that just repeating everything?

```
const playButton = document.querySelector("#btnPlay");
const playButton1 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay1");
const playButton2 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay2");
const playButton3 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay3");
const playButton4 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay4");
const playButton5 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay5");
const playButton6 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay6");
const playButton7 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay7");
const playButton8 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay8");
const playButton9 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay9");
const playButton10 = document.querySelector("#btnPlay10");

const pauseButton = document.querySelector("#btnPause");
const pauseButton1 = document.querySelector("#btnPause1");
const pauseButton2 = document.querySelector("#btnPause2");
const pauseButton3 = document.querySelector("#btnPause3");
const pauseButton4 = document.querySelector("#btnPause4");
const pauseButton5 = document.querySelector("#btnPause5");
const pauseButton6 = document.querySelector("#btnPause6");
const pauseButton7 = document.querySelector("#btnPause7");
const pauseButton8 = document.querySelector("#btnPause8");
const pauseButton9 = document.querySelector("#btnPause9");
const pauseButton10 = document.querySelector("#btnPause10");

const iframe = document.querySelector("#player");
const iframe1 = document.querySelector("#player1");
const iframe2 = document.querySelector("#player2");
const iframe3 = document.querySelector("#player3");
const iframe4 = document.querySelector("#player4");
const iframe5 = document.querySelector("#player5");
const iframe6 = document.querySelector("#player6");
const iframe7 = document.querySelector("#player7");
const iframe8 = document.querySelector("#player8");
const iframe9 = document.querySelector("#player9");
const iframe10 = document.querySelector("#player10");
        
const player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
const player1 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe1);
const player2 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe2);
const player3 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe3);
const player4 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe4);
const player5 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe5);
const player6 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe6);
const player7 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe7);
const player8 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe8);
const player9 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe9);
const player10 = new Vimeo.Player(iframe10);

playButton.addEventListener("click", playVideo);
playButton1.addEventListener("click", playVideo1);
playButton2.addEventListener("click", playVideo2);
playButton3.addEventListener("click", playVideo3);
playButton4.addEventListener("click", playVideo4);
playButton5.addEventListener("click", playVideo5);
playButton6.addEventListener("click", playVideo6);
playButton7.addEventListener("click", playVideo7);
playButton8.addEventListener("click", playVideo8);
playButton9.addEventListener("click", playVideo9);
playButton10.addEventListener("click", playVideo10);

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo);
pauseButton1.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo1);
pauseButton2.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo2);
pauseButton3.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo3);
pauseButton4.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo4);
pauseButton5.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo5);
pauseButton6.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo6);
pauseButton7.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo7);
pauseButton8.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo8);
pauseButton9.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo9);
pauseButton10.addEventListener("click", pauseVideo10);

function playVideo() {
    player.play();
}
function playVideo1() {
    player1.play();
}
function playVideo2() {
    player2.play();
}
function playVideo3() {
    player3.play();
}
function playVideo4() {
    player4.play();
}
function playVideo5() {
    player5.play();
}
function playVideo6() {
    player6.play();
}
function playVideo7() {
    player7.play();
}
function playVideo8() {
    player8.play();
}
function playVideo9() {
    player9.play();
}
function playVideo10() {
    player10.play();
}


function pauseVideo() {
    player.pause();
    player.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo1() {
    player1.pause();
  player1.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo2() {
    player2.pause();
  player2.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo3() {
    player3.pause();
  player3.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo4() {
    player4.pause();
  player4.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo5() {
    player5.pause();
  player5.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo6() {
    player6.pause();
  player6.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo7() {
    player7.pause();
  player7.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo8() {
    player8.pause();
  player8.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo9() {
    player9.pause();
  player9.setCurrentTime(0);
}
function pauseVideo10() {
    player10.pause();
  player10.setCurrentTime(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable for each of these, you can use arrays for the buttons, iframes, and players, and you can use anonymous functions for the click event listeners.

```js
const playerCount = 11;
const playButtons = new Array(playerCount)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => document.querySelector(`#btnPlay${i || ""}`));
const pauseButtons = new Array(playerCount)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => document.querySelector(`#btnPause${i || ""}`));
const iframes = new Array(playerCount)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => document.querySelector(`#player${i || ""}`));

const players = iframes.map((iframe) => new Vimeo.Player(iframe));

players.forEach((player, index) => {
  playButtons[index].addEventListener("click", player.play);
  pauseButtons[index].addEventListener("click", () => {
    player.pause();
    player.setCurrentTime(0);
  });
});
```

`.fill(0)` is needed because `new Array(size)` has "empty" elements, which are skipped over by `.map`.

`${i || ""}` is part of a template literal, this makes it so that if the value is 0 it's an empty string.

Another approach is a traditional for-loop. If you don't need to store a reference to each of buttons, etc., that you can access later, this option can be considered "cleaner" since it doesn't have extra variables leak out into the surrounding scope.

```js
const playerCount = 11;

// if you need this
// const players = [];
// you can also repeat this for other variables you want outside of this loop

for (let i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
  const playButton = document.querySelector(`#btnPlay${i || ""}`);
  const pauseButton = document.querySelector(`#btnPause${i || ""}`);
  const iframe = document.querySelector(`#player${i || ""}`);

  const player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

  playButton.addEventListener("click", player.play);
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    player.pause();
    player.setCurrentTime(0);
  });

  // if you need this
  // players.push(player);
}
```

Speed isn't an issue for something this small (only 11 players). The choice is mostly just stylistic and whatever you find to be the most readable.